# Is there an established way to convert a Tensorflow network architecture written in graph/session, to Keras API for TPU use?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In order to use Google TPU, your code must either use the Estimator API or Keras API.

Converting a graph to use the Estimator API is pretty straight forward, as you mostly allocate the code among model_fn, features, input_fn, etc.

Converting to graph to Keras is not as straight forward, as Keras has unique functions and datatypes to handle various operations. However, from Tensorflow's blog post, they seem to recommend Keras over Estimator

https://medium.com/tensorflow/standardizing-on-keras-guidance-on-high-level-apis-in-tensorflow-2-0-bad2b04c819a.

> By establishing Keras as the high-level API for TensorFlow, we are
>   making it easier for developers new to machine learning to get started
>   with TensorFlow.
>
> That said, if you are working on custom architectures, we suggest
>   using tf.keras to build your models instead of Estimator.

The Tensorflow Keras API is built on top of Tensorflow though, so I'm guessing there's a way to make anything in Tensorflow also in keras, especially since there seems to be functions that directly convert a Tensorflow function to keras, such as `keras.optimizers.TFOptimizer(<tensorflow optimizer>)`

Is there an established way to convert any architecture coded using graph/session to the Keras API?

Comment: Is your issue resolved now? Else, This `Migration Guide `(https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) and this `TPU Tutorial` (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tpu) should help you to convert code from `Tensorflow (1.x)` to `TF Keras (2.x)`. Thanks!

Comment: yes, I have resolved the issue